# Sumar múltiplos de 10 enteros en C#

Tags: c#

Necesito ayuda. Me han pedido un **programa**, que lea diez enteros y los almacene en un vector y después, que lea un número y sume los múltiplos de los **diez enteros** que ha leído anteriormente, pero me sale el siguiente error:

**Lo que debería de salir:**

> ```
> Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value:
> ```
>
> Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value:
> Insert integer value: Insert integer for multiple value:
> The sum of given values in positions multiples of 2 is 30.
> Press any key.

**Lo que sale:**

> ```
> Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value:
> ```
>
> Insert integer value: Insert integer value: Insert integer value:
> Insert integer value: Insert integer for multiple value: The sum of
> given values in positions multiples of 2 is 56
> Press any key.

**Código de la aplicación:**

````
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10;
        string num11, num12, num13, num14, num15, num16, num17, num18, num19, num20;
        int mult;
        string mult1;
        int resultado = 0;
        int result = 0;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num11 = Console.ReadLine();
        num1 = int.Parse(num11);
        resultado += num1;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num12 = Console.ReadLine();
        num2 = int.Parse(num12);
        resultado += num2;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num13 = Console.ReadLine();
        num3 = int.Parse(num13);
        resultado += num3;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num14 = Console.ReadLine();
        num4 = int.Parse(num14);
        resultado += num4;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num15 = Console.ReadLine();
        num5 = int.Parse(num15);
        resultado += num5;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num16 = Console.ReadLine();
        num6 = int.Parse(num16);
        resultado += num6;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num17 = Console.ReadLine();
        num7 = int.Parse(num17);
        resultado += num7;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num18 = Console.ReadLine();
        num8 = int.Parse(num18);
        resultado += num8;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num19 = Console.ReadLine();
        num9 = int.Parse(num19);
        resultado += num9;
        Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
        num20 = Console.ReadLine();
        num10 = int.Parse(num20);
        Console.Write("Insert integer for multiple value: ");
        mult1 = Console.ReadLine();
        mult = int.Parse(mult1);
        resultado += num10;
        while (resultado > 0)
        {
            if (num1%mult== 0)
            {
                result = result + num1;
                resultado = resultado - num1;
            } else if (num2%mult== 0)
            {
                result = result + num2;
                resultado = resultado - num2;
            } else if (num3%mult== 0)
            {
                result = result + num3;
                resultado = resultado - num3;
            } else if (num4%mult== 0) { 
                result = result + num4;
                resultado = resultado - num4;
            } else if (num5%mult== 0)
            {
                result = result + num5;
                resultado = resultado - num5;
            } else if (num6%mult== 0)
            {
                result = result + num6;
                resultado = resultado - num6;
            } else if (num7%mult== 0) { 
                result = result + num7;
                resultado = resultado - num7;
            } else if (num8%mult== 0)
            {
                result = result + num8;
                resultado = resultado - num8;
            } else if (num9%mult== 0)
            {
                result = result + num9;
                resultado = resultado - num9;
            } else if (num10%mult== 0)
            {
                result = result + num10;
                resultado = resultado - num10;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of given values in positions multiples of " + mult + " is " + result);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
    }
}```
````

Comment: No estaría mal que pusieras también la entrada del programa.

Comment: es donde pone "lo que sale"

Comment: Me refiero a los números que lee el programa.

Comment: son 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 y 10

Comment: Ya sé que puedes estar iniciando en la programación, pero aún así, date cuenta que estás repitiendo código. Veo que ya conoces los ciclos así que, es cuestión de que uses un arreglo para guardar todos los números y un ciclo que se encargue de hacer la misma acción por cada uno. Por cierto, no necesitas 10  variables de tipo string, al final solo usas su valor numérico así que con una sola te alcanza.

Comment: Entiendo. Que lineas deberia de cambiar y como?

Comment: No olvides marcar como aceptada la respuesta que más te gustó, y si lo consideras darle un voto al resto de las respuestas correctas

Comment: Ok, apenas soy nuevo aquí. A partir de ahora lo haré.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que en realidad tienes un problema de comprensión. Deduciendo el propósito del programa en base a su entrada, lo que tienes que hacer es:

- Leer 10 números enteros.
- Leer otro número.
- Sumar los números en las posiciones que son múltiplos del número anterior.

Se puede comprobar que si ingresamos los números que dijiste en los comentarios obtenemos el resultado esperado:

| Posiciones | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Números | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

Usando 2 como el número del que deben ser múltiplos, si sumas los números en las posiciones 0, 2, 4, 6 y 8 el resultado no da. (1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 25). Pero las impares sí 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = 30.

Así que debe ser que el problema plantea la numeración empezando del 1:

| Posiciones | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Números | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

O también es posible que el problema no sea claro.

---

Así que evitando repetir código, arreglado quedaría así:

```
// En lugar de crear 10 variables individuales, mejor usa un arreglo.
int[] numeros = new int[10];

// La entrada solo se utiliza una vez. Mejor reutilizar una sola variable.
string entrada;

int multiplo;
int resultado = 0;

// De aquí en adelante se hace la lectura de las variables
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Console.Write("Insert integer value: ");
    entrada = Console.ReadLine();
    numeros[i] = int.Parse(entrada);
}

Console.Write("Insert integer for multiple value: ");
entrada = Console.ReadLine();
multiplo = int.Parse(entrada);

// Aquí se procesan las variables
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    // Convertir posiciones según la numeración del ejercicio
    int posicion = i + 1;
    bool esMultiplo = posicion % multiplo == 0;

    if (esMultiplo)
        resultado += numeros[i];
}

// Y aquí se da el resultado final.
Console.WriteLine("The sum of given values in positions multiples of " + multiplo + " is " + resultado);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
```

Si prestas atención, con un arreglo y muchas líneas menos puedes lograr lo mismo. ***No trabajes duro, trabaja inteligentemente***.

Nota: [`int.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse) lanza una excepción si el string no contiene un número válido. Tal vez prefieras usar [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse).

Comment: Ya lo solucioné con eso, ahora voy a ver como funciona el código y qué hace cada cosa.

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir elementos al vector puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
int[] vector = new int[10];
int numero = 0;

Console.WriteLine("A continuación debe escribir 10 números para llenar un vector.");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Escriba un número:");

   int numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
   vector[i] = numero;         
}

//Ahora filtras los múltiplos de 10 y los sumas.
int suma = vector.Where(n => n % 10 == 0).Sum();

Console.WriteLine("La suma de los números múltiplos de 10 es: {0}", suma);
```

Haces un **ciclo for** donde le pides al usuario que vaya introduciendo **10** números, y estos números lo almacenas en un arreglo.

Posteriormente haciendo uso de **Linq** filtras los números que son múltiplos de **10** y los sumas, finalmente muestras la suma en pantalla.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: me sale error en: int numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: Que error te sale

Comment: ya lo solucioné, no te preocupes.